# How do I get Nvidia graphics working with kernel 5.10 on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm trying to get Nvidia working with 5.10 rc6. I have downloaded kernel, header and image from here [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10-rc6/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10-rc6/amd64/) and everything seems to work ok. I have a 5950x and 5.10 added support for AMD Zen 3 CPU temperature monitoring so it works as well. I have installed nvidia drivers from PPA and version is 455.45.01. When I install the 5.10 kernel I get error:

```
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=5.10.0-051000rc6-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.10.0-051000rc6-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.10.0-051000rc6-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.0-051000rc6-generic (x86_64)
```

Do I need to remove current drivers and install they manually using `.run` package or how I should approach this? I have 2x3090fe cards.

Comment: `linux-headers-5.10.0-051000rc6-generic is not supported` - you will likely have a hard time to get it working regardless of what you do.

Comment: I tried kernel 5.10.3 with GPU Nvidia 1660ti driver 455.45.01 on Ubuntu 20.04 with "relative" success but the Nvidia X server settings is blank and I can't check the graphics card temp using Psensor. I don't know if the beta driver from Nvidia 460.X is any better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the latest [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10/amd64/) seems to work properly with drivers from PPA (455.45.01).

Answer (score 1):

upgrade to

LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER

Version:    455.45.01

Link bellow:

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/166883/en-us

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1299918/167850

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Arch Linux, I have the latest kernel 5.10.3, I found the Nvidia Linux Beta Driver 460.27.04-1 seems to work.

**Note**: It is a beta driver, some things might not work.

Answer (score 0):

The current version (455.45.01) does not work out-of-box with kernel version 5.10

I did the following to build it regardless:

Inside the nvidia installation package (after having installed the DKMS debian package), you need to circumvent the Modules.symvers check.

/usr/src/nvidia-455.45.01/conftest.sh:4527

That's where I inserted an "exit 0" (to force the same behaviour as if $IGNORE_MISSING_MODULE_SYMVERS was set).

For people that built the kernel themselves:

Also make sure your headers have a complete Modules.symvers

It needs to include the module symbols as well as symbols from vmlinux (mainly __close_fd). So make sure to "make vmlinux" in your kernel tree, then "make modules" (again) to rebuild Modules.symvers

```
0x00000000  __close_fd  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
```

This line needs to be present.

EDIT:

Seeing that this is nearly impossible to pull off with the debian source files and also make use of the i386 files, I suggest you to uninstall the Debian packages, extract the installer using "--extract-only", patch the conftest.sh as mentioned and run the installer manually.